# Do pulled hair from the root grow back?

Tags: hair

There is not much to explain, I'm wondering if pulled hair, for example of the head, normally does grow back again or not. [In reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/44p6pg/why_does_a_hair_come_back_if_i_pull_it_out_by_the/), It says this may depend on the follicle integrity, if the follicle is  not hurt then it will grow back and viceversa. It is the case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> There's no harm in plucing a hair, but it won't do you much good

Plucking the hair will indeed get rid of the hair - but only temporarily

> "The follicle (the little tube beneath the skin that produces the
>   hair) is still alive and will produce another hair to replace the one
>   that was pulled out

So actually if you DON'T damage the follicle (which is really rare, this could be the case if you remove skin) the hair will definitly grow back.
To get into more depth here is a figure that shows the root and the follicle so it's clear what the difference is: 
[image]

I don't know in how much depth you want this question to be answered but if you are interested in the growth stages (which can influence the hair regrowth) you should take a look at [this](https://www.quora.com/Does-pulled-out-hair-grow-back) answer, I won't copy someone else effort here..

*source: Randy Schueller ([link](http://www.today.com/health/myth-busted-does-plucking-gray-hairs-make-more-grow-back-t73481))*